# Ability to provide keypair to solana spl-token command

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

I'm performing a call of this CLI function

`spl-token balance --token--`

So it requires a keypair.json file to be present at this location `~ .config/solana/id.json` (for Mac)

Without this file CLI throws an error

> error: No such file or directory (os error 2)

Is there a way to specify a path to keypair or even better specify the whole file content (encoded or not) as a CLI param?

BTW this issue is not limited to just this command, most of spl-token cli commands I've tried has this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify the keypair directly, you can use the `--fee-payer` argument, ie:

```
$ spl-token --fee-payer id.json balance --owner <YOUR_PUBKEY> <TOKEN_MINT_PUBKEY>
```

The `--fee-payer` argument accepts a few different possibilities, including keypair files, or even keywords that accept input from stdin.  More information at https://docs.solana.com/wallet-guide/paper-wallet#hierarchical-derivation

It isn't super intuitive, but the possibility is there.  For example, a balance check shouldn't need a signer.  PRs / suggestions for improvement are always accepted on GitHub! https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library

Comment: Is it possible to supply the `--owner` for `spl-token transfer` as a string (bs58 encoded) instead of a file-path to the disk?

Comment: No, because the owner must sign the transaction in order to transfer.  Otherwise, you could transfer from anyone else's wallet and into yours!

Comment: Yeah, I get that you need the private key to authorize, I am asking if I can provide it as a string instead of the file path. So that I can store it in memory instead of a file on the disk.

Comment: Jon, I created an feature request issue 
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues/2877
I will be more than happy to work on this if the team decides this is appropriate

Comment: Great, that'll be your best bet, since you're right, you can't provide the keypair as a base58-encoded string.  As a workaround, you could use any of the other formats currently supported, such as the secret key seed words, provided via stdin.  Your change would start in https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/86c3990c25920d0619beaba213ca8acf284842f4/clap-utils/src/keypair.rs#L752 and https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/86c3990c25920d0619beaba213ca8acf284842f4/clap-utils/src/keypair.rs#L442 to support a new format similar to the `Pubkey` format.

Comment: In our conversation with Trent in the GH issue I linked to it was decided that this is not needed. Anyway thank you for your help. I'm sure when I get more knowledgable about Solana I'll get to contribute something to this great project!

Comment: That would be much appreciated -- looking forward to seeing some PRs from  you then!

Answer (score 0):

This has always been possible with the `prompt://` argument, which enabled [paper wallets](https://docs.solana.com/wallet-guide/paper-wallet). For USDC:

> spl-token transfer EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v <AMOUNT> <RECIPIENT_ADDRESS> --fund-recipient --allow-unfunded-recipient --owner prompt:// --fee-payer prompt://

You'll then be able to paste the private keys of the owner and the fee payer.